# How to merge 3 queries from 2 tables.(determining min row difference of date and display all fields from 2 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

**legal** table with two fields ARP and legal date

```
+--------+-----------+
|  ARP   | legaldate |
+--------+-----------+
|  71698 | 1/22/2016 |
|  82501 | 4/28/2016 |
| 103451 | 5/22/2016 |
|   1111 | 1/2/2016  |
+--------+-----------+
```

**intake** table with 3 fields Intake,ARP and Intake Date

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| Intake |  ARP  | IntakeDate |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 615729 | 71698 | 12/9/2015  |
| 615891 | 71698 | 12/10/2015 |
| 620697 | 71698 | 1/19/2016  |
| 621681 | 71698 | 1/26/2016  |
| 621711 | 71698 | 1/26/2016  |
| 630455 | 82501 | 4/28/2016  |
| 634946 | 82501 | 3/30/2016  |
| 123009 |  1111 | 9/2/2016   |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

I join ARP of both tables and find date diff between legaldate and intake date( Display all fields from both tables- using **query 1**

I find the min date diff between legal date and intake date (display only 'min diff' and 'ARP')- using **query 2**

I join Query 1 and query 2 by date diff/mindatediff and ARP/ARP to get the desire results-**query 3** (Min date diff with all fields from both tables)

Final display I get **(UNIQUE ARP WITH MIN DATE DIFF BETWEEN LEGAL DATE AND INTAKE DATE)**

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  ARP  | Intake Date | legaldate | DateDiff |
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 71698 | 1/19/2016   | 1/22/2016 |        3 |
| 82501 | 4/28/2016   | 4/28/2016 |        0 |
|  1111 | 9/2/2016    | 1/2/2016  |      244 |
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

I run 3 queries ( I  discover I can get these result in two queries too).
I WANT TO BE EFFICIENT and get desire result in one query.

My 3 queries are

1) Find the difference in date  using **'intake-risk'** query

```
SELECT Intake.Intake, legal.ARP, Intake.[Intake Date], legal.legaldate, Abs([legal]![legaldate]-[Intake]![Intake Date]) AS Diff
FROM Intake RIGHT JOIN legal ON Intake.ARP = legal.ARP;
```

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------+
|  Intake  |    ARP    | Intake Date | legaldate | Diff |
+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------+
| 621711   |     71698 | 1/26/2016   | 1/22/2016 |    4 |
| 621681   |     71698 | 1/26/2016   | 1/22/2016 |    4 |
| 620697   |     71698 | 1/19/2016   | 1/22/2016 |    3 |
| 615891   |     71698 | 12/10/2015  | 1/22/2016 |   43 |
| 615729   |     71698 | 12/9/2015   | 1/22/2016 |   44 |
| 634946   |     82501 | 3/30/2016   | 4/28/2016 |   29 |
| 630455   |     82501 | 4/28/2016   | 4/28/2016 |    0 |
| Blank... |    103451 | 5/22/2016   |           |      |
| 123009   |      1111 | 9/2/2016    | 1/2/2016  |  244 |
+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------+
```

2) Find Min date Diff using **'Mindatediff'** query

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [legal].ARP, Min(Abs([legal]!legaldate-Intake![Intake Date])) AS datediff
FROM Intake INNER JOIN legal ON Intake.ARP=[legal].ARP
GROUP BY [legal].ARP;
```

```
+-------+-----------+
|  ARP  |  datediff |
+-------+-----------+
|  1111 |       244 |
| 71698 |         3 |
| 82501 |         0 |
+-------+-----------+
```

3) Query **'Mindate-legalbegin'** to get the final result.

```
SELECT [intake-risk].legal.ARP, [intake-risk].[Intake Date], [intake-risk].legaldate, Mindatediff.DateDiff
FROM Mindatediff INNER JOIN [intake-risk] ON (Mindatediff.ARP = [intake-risk].Intake.ARP) AND (Mindatediff.datediff = [intake-risk].diff);
```

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  ARP  | Intake Date |   legaldate |    DateDiff |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 71698 | 1/19/2016   | 1/22/2016   |           3 |
| 82501 | 4/28/2016   | 4/28/2016   |           0 |
|  1111 | 9/2/2016    | 1/2/2016    |         244 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**I want to get the final result just by running one query on two tables!** **(UNIQUE ARP WITH MIN DATE DIFF BETWEEN LEGAL DATE AND INTAKE DATE)**

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: This is a strange SQL syntax. Those non-standard brackets around names I only know from SQL-Server and MS Access. The exclamation mark between table name and column name suggests MS Access again. And subtracting one date from another works in some DBMS (e.g. Oracle), but when I tried this in MySQL that didn't work either. Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

P.D,

is it what you need?

I am not sure how you structured your db, so I have recreated it.

```
      DROP DATABASE LegalDB;
            CREATE DATABASE LegalDB;
            SHOW DATABASES ;
            USE LegalDB;

            CREATE TABLE Legal (
              legARP INT NOT NULL,
              legLegalDate DATE NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (legARP)
            );

            CREATE TABLE Intake(
              intIntake INT NOT NULL,
              intARP INT NOT NULL,
              intIntakeDate DATE NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (intIntake)
            );

            INSERT INTO Legal
                     (legARP, legLegalDate)
                   VALUES
                     (71698, '2016-01-22'),
                     (82501, '2016-04-28'),
                     (103451, '2016-05-22'),
                     (1111, '2016-01-02');

            INSERT INTO Intake
                          (intIntake, intARP, intIntakeDate)
                   VALUES
                     (615729,71698 ,'2015-12-09'),
                     (615891, 71698, '2015-12-10'),
                     (620697, 71698 , '2016-01-19' ),
                     (621681, 71698 , '2016-01-26'),
                     (621711, 71698 , '2016-01-26'),
                     (630455, 82501, '2016-04-28'),
                     (634946, 82501 , '2016-03-30'),
                     (123009, 1111, '2016-09-02');



   -- --------------------------------------
   -- this query SHOWS +/- sign
   -- --------------------------------------             
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT legARP, 
        (SELECT datediff(intIntakeDate, legLegalDate)) as dateDifference
        FROM Legal
        RIGHT JOIN Intake
        ON intARP = legARP
        ORDER BY legARP, ABS(dateDifference)) as selection
    GROUP BY legARP;


        This will produce the following:

          +--------+----------------+
          | legARP | dateDifference |
          +--------+----------------+
          |   1111 |            244 |
          |  71698 |             -3 |
          |  82501 |              0 |
          +--------+----------------+


   -- --------------------------------------
   -- this query DOES NOT show +/- sign
   -- -------------------------------------- 

SELECT * FROM (SELECT legARP, (SELECT ABS(datediff(intIntakeDate, legLegalDate))) as dateDifference
FROM Legal
RIGHT JOIN Intake
ON intARP = legARP
ORDER BY legARP, dateDifference) AS SELECTION
GROUP BY legARP;

 This will produce the following:

      +--------+----------------+
      | legARP | dateDifference |
      +--------+----------------+
      |   1111 |            244 |
      |  71698 |              3 |
      |  82501 |              0 |
      +--------+----------------+
```

Edited with the addition of the dates displayed.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT legARP, intIntakeDate, legLegalDate, 
      (SELECT ABS(datediff(intIntakeDate, legLegalDate))) 
             as dateDifference
       FROM Legal
       RIGHT JOIN Intake
       ON intARP = legARP
       ORDER BY legARP, dateDifference) AS SELECTION
GROUP BY legARP;
```

This will produce the exact output requested:

```
+--------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| legARP | intIntakeDate | legLegalDate | dateDifference |
+--------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|   1111 | 2016-09-02    | 2016-01-02   |            244 |
|  71698 | 2016-01-19    | 2016-01-22   |              3 |
|  82501 | 2016-04-28    | 2016-04-28   |              0 |
+--------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Please note that the dates as shown in the questions are not standards.
The dates should be stored as YYYY-MM-DD as documented on the Mysql manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL lacks analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER`. This makes such tasks difficult in MySQL and the queries rather slow.

I see two ways for MySQL to do this in one query. Which of them is faster depends on table sizes and some other things.

1) A minimum date diff is the one for which exists no smaller date diff:

```
select
  l.arp,
  i.intakedate,
  l.legaldate,
  abs(datediff(l.legaldate, i.intakedate)) as datediff
from legal l
join intake i on i.arp = l.arp
where not exists
(
  select *
  from intake i2
  where i2.arp = i.arp
  and abs(datediff(l.legaldate, i2.intakedate)) < abs(datediff(l.legaldate, i.intakedate))
);
```

2) Select the minimum date differences and use this to access the table again:

```
select
  agg.arp,
  i2.intakedate,
  agg.legaldate,
  agg.datediff
from 
(
  select
    l.arp,
    l.legaldate,
    min(abs(datediff(l.legaldate, i1.intakedate))) as datediff
  from legal l
  join intake i1 on i1.arp = l.arp
  group by l.arp, l.legaldate
) agg
join intake i2 on i2.arp = agg.arp 
               and abs(datediff(agg.legaldate, i2.intakedate)) = agg.datediff;
```